# Issue with multiple selected index queries (select option menu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I have 2 select option menu's:**

```
<select name="cylinder" class="cylinder" id="cylinder">
 <option value="0" selected="selected">Please select from the options below...</option>
 <option value="500">£500 for 230 Litres (2000 x 400 / 2-3 people)</option>
 <option value="550">£550 for 260 Litres (1800 x 450 / 2-3 people)</option>
 <option value="600">£600 for 290 Litres (2000 x 450 / 3-4 people)</option>
 <option value="650">£650 for 320 Litres (1800 x 500 / 4-5 people)</option>
 <option value="700">£700 for 350 Litres (2000 x 500 / 5-6 people)</option>
 <option value="800">£800 for 512 Litres (2000 x 600 / 6-7 people)</option>
</select>

<select name="heatex" class="cylinder" id="heatex">
 <option value="0" selected="selected">Please select from the options below...</option>
 <option value="250">£250 for an Internal Mains Coil 110 Kw</option>
 <option value="350">£350 for an Internal Mains Coil 110 Kw with Twin Mixer Upgrade</option>
 <option value="400">£400 for an Internal Mains Coil 165 Kw</option>                              
 <option value="500">£500 for an Internal Mains Coil 165 Kw with Twin Mixer Upgrade</option>
 <option value="700">£700 for an External Plate Exchanger 165</option>
</select>
```

**and the following JavaScript code to store the value of the selected option**

```
function next_section()
 {
   var a = document.getElementById("cylinder").selectedIndex;  
   var num = new Number(document.getElementsByTagName("option")[a].value);

   var b = document.getElementById("heatex").selectedIndex;
   var num2 = new Number(document.getElementsByTagName("option")[b].value);

   document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = (num+num2);
 }
```

**I have a button to call the function:**

```
<img src="buildernext.jpg" onClick="next_section(1)"/>
```

**The purpose of the function is to update the following text:**

```
Basic Thermal Store: &nbsp;&pound;<span id="total">0.00</span>
```

**My error/problem:**

Basically, if you select the 4th option under the "heatex" select menu then the function will grab the 4th option value from the "cylinder" select menu instead. I can only assume that my issue is trying to get 2 lots of selected indexes? I'm not sure, any and all help appreciated.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? I see it that you added the tag in the question but I don't see any jQuery code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your JS code use the below:

```
function next_section()
{
   var a = document.getElementById("cylinder");  
   var num = Number(a.options[a.selectedIndex].value);

   var b = document.getElementById("heatex");
   var num2 = Number(b.options[b.selectedIndex].value);

   document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = (num+num2);
 }
```

Comment: I think the second one should be `document.getElementById("heatex").value`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you can see the code there is `heatex` in the second.

Comment: It wasn't in the original, you little ninja editor ;) I've upvoted you anyway.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that time you are commenting I was editing the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
function next_section()
{
   var selectA = document.getElementById("cylinder");
   var num = selectA.options[selectA.selectedIndex].value;

   var selectB = document.getElementById("heatex");
   var num2 = selectB.options[selectB.selectedIndex].value;

   document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = (num+num2);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good solution for you : (using jquery)

```
$('#selectForm').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    next_section();
});
function next_section()
 {
     var num1 = parseInt($("#cylinder").val());  
     var num2 = parseInt($("#heatex").val());

   $('#total').html(num1+num2);
 }
```